# How do I make files with a specific extension be added to a commit automatically?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I'm trying to figure out how to automatically add all files of a certain extension (for example *.tex) to the commit dialogue (the checkbox should already be checked! I don't want to search for the new files every single time)

I tried adding *.tex to the auto-commit list (=comma separated list) but that doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mercurial has so called *hooks* to do stuff automatically on certain events. See also the [hgrc documentation](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#hooks) and the [Mercurial wiki page on Hooks](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Hook).

Your task can be done with a *pre-commit* hook, defined in your repository's *hgrc* file:

```
[hooks]
pre-commit = hg add -I "*.tex"
```

Before a commit, this hook automatically adds all not yet tracked *tex* files in the root of the repository's current working directory. Adjust the value of the `-I` option or add more `-I` options to specify more complex patterns of files to add automatically.

**Note:** I don't use TortoiseHG, so I cannot say if this hook causes any *checkboxes* to be pre-selected. Anyway, it should also work if you commit with TortoiseHG.

Comment: Something must have changed in newer hg versions, I am unable to hg add in pre-commit hook due to the current instance of hg locking the `.hg` folder with a `wlock` file, any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure you used `pre-commit` (with a hyphen) and not `precommit`= The latter one is a bit different (see HGRC hooks help).

Comment: Oben, it's been a while but yes that was the case!

Answer (score 1):

In hg as console application this very simple solution works, too:

```
hg add "*.tex"
```